# Custom or Virtual Keyboard on Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-virtual-keyboard

I wish to create my own custom keyboard on android. It seems the below project on google code project should be able to achieve this. But to extension to this what I also want to add is ability to handle browser events when user is using custom keyboard.  ie if user clicks on browser address bar or any text box on the page opened I should be able to determine that as well? Is there a way possible?

http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/source/checkout

Thanks,
nil

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, but I think you are asking how to create a keyboard that is used when the user clicks on textfields in other apps. Is that right?

If you want to create your own virtual keyboard then you should definitely start by reading the [Android IME Docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) they are really good and even provide [code for a example keyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html) that you can download.

Comment: thanks slayton you are right I want to handle user clicks on textfields in other applications.

Comment: so is that possible ie handle user clicks on textfields in other applications using custom IME?